# Only SQL Server Enterprise Edition supports compression - how to work around that?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, scripting, standard-edition

I have a script that needs to create a temp table and in that temp table I create an index.

I noticed in some of my servers, the script would go on forever, and when [checking from a different session what is currently running](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111699/22336) there was no clear message available.

after cancelling the query I get this message:

```
Message: 
Cannot enable compression for object '#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions__________________________________________________________________________________________0000000A923A'. 
Only SQL Server Enterprise Edition supports compression.  
Error: 7738 
Severity: 16
```

this is the part of the script that is generating this error message:

```
IF object_id('TEMPDB..#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions

    create table #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions (
        publisher sysname NOT NULL,  
        publisher_db sysname NOT NULL, 
        publication sysname NOT NULL, 
        replication_type int,
        subscription_type int,
        last_updated datetime,
        subscriberd_db sysname,
        update_mode int,
        last_sync_status int,
        last_sync_summary nvarchar(4000),
        last_sync_time datetime)

   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX I_RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions
                       ON #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions (publisher,Publisher_db,publication)
                     WITH (   PAD_INDEX = OFF
                            , FILLFACTOR = 100  
                            , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
                            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
                            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
                            , ONLINE = OFF
                            , DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE
                            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
                            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[Later on](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/216045/22336) this is what I store in this table:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

TRUNCATE TABLE #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions

insert into #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions
exec sp_MSenumsubscriptions

select * from #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions
```

which gives this valuable info:

[image]

Comment: I don't think your script "went on forever" because the feature wasn't supported on that edition. That error message should have been returned immediately, not after canceling.

Comment: Exactly, I agree, and that's exactly why I've put all the story in. It uses your [sp_ineachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5686/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-using-spineachdb/) by the way.

Comment: If this is such a small table there is not much need for bothering with compression anyway, just remove the data_compression clause.

Comment: What you probably saw is the script getting an error and the error message being buffered and then it going onto another long running statement that didn't return anything to the client so the error message stayed buffered then when you cancelled the query the packet was finally sent to the client. e.g. As `RAISERROR ('Some error message', 16,1);WAITFOR DELAY '23:59:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking [this link about sql server version check](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/) and this one below as well:

[How do you find SQL Server version/edition without SSMS installed?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/67988/22336)

I have just got this script to check what he have in the current server:

```
  SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '8%' THEN 'SQL2000'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '9%' THEN 'SQL2005'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.0%' THEN 'SQL2008'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '10.5%' THEN 'SQL2008 R2'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '11%' THEN 'SQL2012'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '12%' THEN 'SQL2014'
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '13%' THEN 'SQL2016'     
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '14%' THEN 'SQL2017' 
       --WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('productversion')) like '15%' THEN 'SQL2019' 
       ELSE 'Unknown on April 2019'
    END AS MajorVersion,
      SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') as 'Product Version', 
      SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') as 'Product Level',  
      SERVERPROPERTY('edition') as 'Product Edition',
      SERVERPROPERTY('buildclrversion') as 'CLR Version',
      SERVERPROPERTY('collation') as 'Default Collation',
      SERVERPROPERTY('instancename') as 'Instance',
      SERVERPROPERTY('lcid') as 'LCID',
      SERVERPROPERTY('servername') as 'Server Name',
    SERVERPROPERTY('EditionID') AS 'EditionID'
```

and used it in my create index script down below, after the create table:

```
        IF object_id('TEMPDB..#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions

            create table #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions (
                publisher sysname NOT NULL,  
                publisher_db sysname NOT NULL, 
                publication sysname NOT NULL, 
                replication_type int,
                subscription_type int,
                last_updated datetime,
                subscriberd_db sysname,
                update_mode int,
                last_sync_status int,
                last_sync_summary nvarchar(4000),
                last_sync_time datetime)

           IF ( SELECT RADHE = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')) LIKE '%Enterprise%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) = 1

                   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX I_RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions
                                       ON #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions (publisher,Publisher_db,publication)
                                     WITH (   PAD_INDEX = OFF
                                            , FILLFACTOR = 100  
                                            , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
                                            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
                                            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
                                            , ONLINE = OFF
                                            , DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE
                                            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
                                            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]

           ELSE

                   CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX I_RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions
                                       ON #RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions (publisher,Publisher_db,publication)
                                     WITH (   PAD_INDEX = OFF
                                            , FILLFACTOR = 100  
                                            , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
                                            , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
                                            , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
                                            , ONLINE = OFF
                                            , DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE
                                            , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
                                            , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]


--checking the index creation script
-- EXEC SP_COUNT 'TEMPDB..#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions'

--Results:
 -- SERVER 1 - CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX I_RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions  ON [dbo].[#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions__________________________________________________________________________________________0000000A9250] (  [publisher] ASC  , [publisher_db] ASC  , [publication] ASC  )  WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=NONE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]  GO 
 -- SERVER 2 - CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX I_RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions  ON [dbo].[#RADHE_sp_getsubscriptions__________________________________________________________________________________________00000001B274] (  [publisher] ASC  , [publisher_db] ASC  , [publication] ASC  )  WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]  GO
```

and it is all working fine now.